# Why am I unable to add an edge to an existing Ubergraph graph?

Tags: clojure

Newcomer to both Clojure and the Ubergraph library, so please forgive me if this is blindingly obvious. Trying to add an edge to an existing graph using the Ubergraph add-edges function. The following code works as expected:

```
(def graph1 (uber/graph [:a :b]))
(uber/pprint (uber/add-edges graph1 [:a :c]))
```

...producing the following:

```
3 Nodes:
         :a
         :b
         :c
2 Edges:
         :a <-> :b
         :a <-> :c
```

However, this:

```
(def graph1 (uber/graph [:a :b]))
(uber/add-edges graph1 [:a :c])
(uber/pprint graph1)
```

produces:

```
2 Nodes:
         :a
         :b
1 Edges:
         :a <-> :b
```

The second edge does not get added, although the documentation suggests this is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `(uber/add-edges graph1 [:a :c])` return a brand new graph in both examples while `graph1` remains the same. In first case, you are printing the result. In the second case you don't, you are actually wasting this new graph and printing `graph1`. This is a normal behavior when working with `functional programming`, which applies `immutable data` and `functions with no side effects` concepts.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that might be the case. I'd like to iteratively "append" nodes and edges to a single graph. How do I do that without ending up with a series of duplicate graphs? Can I do that with a recursive function somehow?

Comment: it really depends when you will add nodes and edges. but, generally you would concatenate iteratively using `->` and assign to another var using `let` or `def`. you can either create a `atom` and `swap!` its value.